# Multi Tenant Shared Database (per n number of users)

Tags: database-design, multi-tenant

I am trying to build a multi tenant system. I am looking to create a new Database whenever the current one reaches like 100 users (user details will be stored in a master Database). But I am unsure of how to get this started, I only managed to have one user one database but not 100 users per database. Can anyone give me some advises?

Comment: There are many thoughts to be put into while partitioning the db, like which app related tables to be moved on which of them are going to be shared, the application availability etc. You can also have a customer type like large enterprise and then create a db once you add the customer.

Comment: @Norman You can see similar questions on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/298057/multi-tenant-database-design

Comment: Thanks! Let me read it up.